# How can I get facebook event photos urls using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm playing with facebook explorer to get event photos urls.
For `{event-id}/photos` I get something like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2015-12-07T20:53:44+0000",
      "name": "1913 rok.",
      "id": "178797088851556"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "OTc4Nzk3MDg4ODUxNTU2",
      "after": "OTc4Nzk3MDg4ODUxNTU2"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I exctract this photo (id: 178797088851556) url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s called "Declarative Fields":

```
/{event-id}/photos?fields=name,source
```

Check out the API reference for all available fields.